# Do creating threads in Java may be a bottleneck?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

For continuous task, for example rendering an animation, would creating short lived threads every frame be a lot slower than creating threads at the start and then pausing them and resuming?

Or will the difference be negligible?

Comment: I don't know if it is a language issue, but it's impossible to say if it will be a bottleneck. If you have a really slow system it might not matter, and if it is a really fast system (or framework etc), the fastest option between the several choices might still be a bottleneck?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be a lot slower; threads have a large overhead.

You can use a threadpool to re-use threads and avoid the overhead.
However, it is probably still not worth using threads for such short-lived tasks because the costs of context switches will outweigh the benefits.

***Measure it!***

Comment: I guess threads in my application are not so short-lived as I may have suggested. Profiler showed that thread creation takes close to 0% of time, to confirm I have rewritten my code to use thread pool - no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @mrpyo: Thread creation won't show up in a profiler, since it happens in the OS in the new thread (setting up and allocating the stack, etc). It's still expensive.  (AFAIK)

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new thread has a significant overhead. If the thread has very short activity, the creation overhead may even be bigger than the actual execution time. You will need to recycle threads as much as you can.

I recommend the use of `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new thread is not the best way, due to the creation overhead. Instead of creating new threads, you should at least use a thread pool (see [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) for further details).

Also the life cycle of the threads is important. If it's too short, the performance could be even worse, because of the context-switching overhead.

Another important point is the number of CPU/Cores you have. As a general rule, you should use 1-2 threads per core if your tasks are CPU-intensive (I assume that's your case). You could push this number a little (let's say 3-5 theads) if your tasks are I/O intensive.